# Unhexlify input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a little help with `hexlify` in python.
I want to the user to paste hex data like: `b'EncryptedD4t4'` and it will be unhex .
I tried like:

```
import binascii as b
para1 = str(input())
b.unhexlify(bytes(para1,encoding='utf-8'))
```

And when I run it:

```
b'6578616d706c65'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\filenme.py", line 3, in <module>
    b.unhexlify(bytes(para1,encoding='utf-8'))
binascii.Error: Odd-length string
```

But when I write without `b'` and at last `'` , it works.
I want the user to input it directly with `b'` and `'`.

Comment: Why do you want the user to add them? And if they must, why not just slice `[2:-1]` to get everything but those leading and trailing characters?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks , I tried `[2:]` but I didn't knew how to slice last quote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `b'` and `'` from around the string, a simple way to do this is with slicing:
`b.unhexlify(bytes(para1[2:-1],encoding='utf-8'))`